# Can I access the ::before element with jQuery / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this function to "split" my elements and give them background-colors:

```
var colors = ['red','yellow','green','blue'];

function splitColors($item) {
    $item.each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass(colors[i % 4]);
    });
}

splitColors($('.comment:before'));
```

now I want to apply this function on a before element in my DOM, but it doesn't work.

Can I access the ::before element in jQuery?

I can't use a real element, cause the WordPress comment section don't allow own markup..

Thanks!

Comment: Sry! I'm so stupid! My function add a class to the element ... a before element can't have a class! ... Man that was stupid .. :( @FarzinKanzi

Comment: Yes you right: *before element can't have a class!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works:

```
splitColors($('.comment').before());
```